# Switch statement with multiple choices leading to one code block

Tags: powershell

I am writing a function with multiple parameter sets and I can't seem to get to the correct code block, when basing Switch-statement decisions on the parameter set.

The function is below, but here are the commands and output:

```
Test-Fun -AccessId d -AccessKey d -AccountName d -ObjectType Device -DeviceDisplayName d
```

Output == 1, 2

```
Test-Fun -AccessId d -AccessKey d -AccountName d -ObjectType Device -DeviceName d
```

Output == 1, 3

```
Test-Fun -AccessId d -AccessKey d -AccountName d -ObjectType Device -DeviceID 10
```

Output == 1

```
Test-Fun -AccessId d -AccessKey d -AccountName d -ObjectType Device
```

Output == 1

What gives? Thanks.

```
Function Test-Fun {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='AllDevices')]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='AllDevices')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='IDFilter')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='NameFilter')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='IPFilter')]
        $AccessId,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='AllDevices')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='IDFilter')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='NameFilter')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='IPFilter')]
        $AccessKey,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='AllDevices')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='IDFilter')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='NameFilter')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='IPFilter')]
        $AccountName,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='AllDevices')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='IDFilter')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='NameFilter')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='IPFilter')]
        [ValidateSet("Collector","Device")]
        $ObjectType,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,ParameterSetName='IDFilter')]
        [int]$DeviceId,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,ParameterSetName='NameFilter')]
        [string]$DeviceDisplayName,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,ParameterSetName='IPFilter')]
        [string]$DeviceName
    )

    switch ($PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName) {
        {("IDFilter") -or ("AllDevices")} {
            Write-Host '1'
        }
        ("NameFilter") {
            Write-Host '2'
        }
        ("IPFilter") {
            Write-Host '3'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `{ $_ -in ("IDFilter", "AllDevices") }`

Comment: Or use regex: `switch -regex ($var) { '^(value1|value2)$' { .... } ..... }`